# exsheets and tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, exsheets

What is the problem with this file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes]
  {
    8 & 1 & 6 \\
    3 & 5 & 7 \\
    4 & 9 & 2 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

The compiler says

```
./mini.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options
```

Comment: Workaround: use the `ampersand replacement=\&` and change all `&` into `\&`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`exsheets` reads the body of the `question` environment as argument, hence you can't use `&`, but you can use `ampersand replacement=\&`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}% for cropping
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{question}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of nodes]
  {
    8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
    3 \& 5 \& 7 \\
    4 \& 9 \& 2 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: +1: try to investigate if `exsheet` makes use of `&` for special purposes: it may indicate the cause of the problem.

Comment: `exsheets` doesn't use `&` for anything specific. What it does, though, is reading the environment body as macro argument. Maybe that's the cause...